# When voting about reopening, can/should it be shown why the question was originally closed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, re-open

When voting about reopening, I often go to the question-page to see why it was closed, so as to assess whether or not there have been an improvement in that area.

For instance, I just reviewed a question where OP had included a lot a new math (his/her attempt, I guess), so I automatically saw this as something good. However, when finding out that the close-reason was that the question was unclear, I saw that it was indeed still unclear, and voted to leave closed.

1. Is it wrong to let my decision be influenced by this? I.e. should I look at the question without any knowledge of it's history and decide whether or not it should be closed?
2. If not, could the close-reason be displayed at the voting-page directly?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean in the review queue? Just above the question there are two tabs, "Question (revised)" and "Revision", the second one being displayed by default if a question was put in the review queue after being edited. If you click on "Question (revised)", you see the question with all edits made *and* the reason for which it was closed. If the question was put in the queue e.g. because someone voted to reopen it, you see the close reason by default.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sweet, you're right! Still, the question about whether or not this should influence my assessment stands.

Comment: I don't see why not. I mean, if the question is still unclear, it should remain closed.